# MS SQL text type field in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

In my project I am forced to use columns with text type in my MS SQL (version 2008), due to a datalink with an obscure GIS-system. I am also forced to use triggers to convert the value in the text column to a geometry type value in another column.(for geographical indexing and search)

I know that the text type is not allowed in trigger, but i am trying to find a workaround. As mentioned above it's not an option to change the column type to nvarchar(max).

I have tried with convert(), its not allowed to use a select stement inside this function. And I can't use select directly because of the text type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Function? Huh? Can you show the code you tried please, so we don't have to guess?

Comment: You most likely could change the datatype to varchar(max) even though the legacy system uses it. I have done that in the past with no issue.

Comment: Like @SeanLange said, use varchar(max). As of SQL2005, it holds as much data as text but can be used in places text cannot. Besides TEXT is going away in future versions.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: My problem is that I can't change to nvarchar(max), that's why I ask if someone knows a workaround. But thanks for your comments.

Comment: Why can't you change the datatype? Have you tried it? I have a number of legacy systems that were designed to insert data into text columns. I never had an issue changing those columns to varchar(max).